# Is there a way to substitute dynamic base url in RTK-Query with React Native?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage, rtk-query

I found one way. I can store base url in AsyncStorage so that the user can reload the page and still have access to that url. But there is one problem. I can’t have asynchronous code inside RTK endpoints.

```
const postAuthEndpoint = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: build => ({
    postAuth: build.mutation<PostAuthResponse, PostAuthRequest>({
      query: async data => {
        // throws an error: 
        // Type 'Promise<{ url: string; method: string; body: PostAuthRequest; }>'
        // is not assignable to type 'string | FetchArgs'
        const baseUrl = await AsyncStorage.getItem('baseUrl');

        return {
          url: `${baseUrl}/auth`,
          method: 'POST',
          body: data,
        };
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

Because of this, I decided to create a custom hook, that performs an async operation to get the base url. Then the custom hook passes the base url to the api hook from RTK-Query, which we pass to the custom hook. And returns wrapped mutation with the rest of parameters.

```
export const useEndpointWrapper = (endpoint: any) => {
  const [mutation, ...rest] = endpoint;

  const wrappedMutation = async (args: Request) => {
    const baseUrl = await AsyncStorage.getItem('baseUrl');

    return mutation({ baseUrl, ...args }).unwrap();

  };

  return [wrappedMutation, rest];
};
```

The main disadvantage here is that the TypeScript typing breaks down. This is solvable, but inconvenient.

Maybe there are some other ways to substitute the dynamic base url in react native?